# INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED ERROR While Android CTS TEST

Tags: android, testing, cts, android-cts

cts-tf > run cts -p android.uiautomator

07-23 16:00:48 I/TestInvocation: Starting invocation for 'cts' on build '4.2_r1' on device

0123456789ABCDEF

07-23 16:00:48 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Created result dir 2013.07.23_16.00.48

07-23 16:00:49 E/CtsTest: 
**Failed to install CtsUiAutomatorApp.apk**. **Reason:**

.INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED

07-23 16:01:00 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Collecting device info

07-23 16:01:01 I/0123456789ABCDEF: -----------------------------------------

07-23 16:01:01 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Test package android.uiautomator started

07-23 16:01:01 I/0123456789ABCDEF: -----------------------------------------

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Saved log device_logcat_1318543845250987213.zip

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Saved log host_log_64811981574212401.zip

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: android.uiautomator package complete: Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 34

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Created xml report file at

file:///home/ethan/freescalejb/freescaleandroidjb/./out/host/linux-x86/cts/android-

cts/tools/../../android-cts/repository/results/2013.07.23_16.00.48/testResult.xml

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: XML test result file generated at 2013.07.23_16.00.48.

Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 34

07-23 16:01:02 I/0123456789ABCDEF: Time: 14s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by **Restarting your device**, and by **clearing your project**

`uninstalling` **the previous application**, and than `install` **it again** !

Comment: CtsUiAutomatorApp.apk is an app in cts folder, so to uninstall previous application it should install first :)

Comment: @Ethan try updated answer !

Comment: I tried this morning, but it still can't run at all...I consider that download a brand new cts from Google maybe a good way to go.

Comment: Were you able to run the android.uiautomator? I am finding the same issue.